Kotlinx Serialization: Supporting deserialization for list or just a single element?
I have a list value in a data class that, when only one element is present, may be serialized by only serializing that one element. The serialized value may therefore be a serialized list of elements or a serialized element.
How can I write a serializer (and/or code around it) that supports deserializing this kind of ambiguity, ideally format independently? (JSON and CBOR)
@Serializable
data class ToBeSerialized(val value: List<Int>)

I tried simply writing a serializer that tries to deserialize a list and fallback on single element deserialization, but this for some reason yields a different result (apparently the decoder is consuming characters, realizes that this is not the start of a list, and aborts without rewinding to the original position)
    @Serializable
    data class ToBeSerialized(
        @Serializable(with = SingleOrMultipleValueSerializer::class)
        val value: List<Int>
    )

    object SingleOrMultipleValueSerializer : KSerializer<List<Int>> {
        private val listSerializer = ListSerializer(Int.serializer())

        @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
        override val descriptor = SerialDescriptor(
            serialName = "descriptor",
            original = listSerializer.descriptor
        )

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): List<Int> {
            return try {
                listSerializer.deserialize(decoder)
            } catch (_: Throwable) {
                listOf(Int.serializer().deserialize(decoder))
            }
        }

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: List<Int>) {
            listSerializer.serialize(encoder, value)
        }
    }

I also tried separating the value type into a sealed hierarchy, but this does not seem to work since a polymorphic serializer needs a type discriminator (and I don't really have such a type discriminator, especially not in a primitive Int)
    @Serializable
    data class ToBeSerialized(
        val value: Value
    )

    @Serializable
    sealed interface Value {
        val value: Any

        @Serializable(with = SingleValueSerializer::class)
        data class SingleValue(override val value: Int) : Value

        @Serializable(with = MultipleValuesSerializer::class)
        data class MultipleValues(override val value: List<Int>) : Value
    }

    object SingleValueSerializer : KSerializer<Value.SingleValue> {
        override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor(
            "descriptor1",
            kind = PrimitiveKind.INT,
        )

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Value.SingleValue {
            return Value.SingleValue(decoder.decodeInt())
        }

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Value.SingleValue) {
            encoder.encodeInt(value.value)
        }
    }

    @ExperimentalSerializationApi
    object MultipleValuesSerializer : KSerializer<Value.MultipleValues> {
        private val listSerializer = ListSerializer(Int.serializer())
        override val descriptor = SerialDescriptor(
            serialName = "descriptor2",
            original = listSerializer.descriptor
        )

        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Value.MultipleValues {
            return Value.MultipleValues(
                listSerializer.deserialize(decoder)
            )
        }

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Value.MultipleValues) {
            listSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.value)
        }

    }

Similar questions:

Kotlin serialisation of field that can be String or an Array of Strings :
This question assumes the underlying format to be JSON, but I am looking for a way to do this format-independently

